# Use "import" with Node library, rather than "require"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Newbie Node question here.

I'm trying to use the [Google Cloud Node client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node) with an existing application (not written by me) that bundles its code with rollup.

I've tried importing the library with require, as per its documentation, as follows:

```
 import REGL from "regl/dist/regl";
 import Camera from "./lib/camera";
 ...
 var gcloud = require('google-cloud');
```

But my application complains (CLARIFICATION: it only starts producing this error when I add the `require` statement, otherwise the imports work fine):

```
'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
```

So maybe I need to use `import gcloud` instead of `require`, but how? I tried looking at the code in `node_modules` and doing this instead:

```
import gcloud from "google-cloud/src/index";
```

But now I get a bunch of other errors

```
   Unexpected token
node_modules/google-cloud/node_modules/ent/reversed.json (2:7)
1: {
2:     "9": "Tab;",
      ^
```

How can I use `import` instead of `require`, or alternatively, how can I make `require` play nicely with `import`?

Comment: does all the code fun fine before you add in the `var gcloud = require('google-cloud')` ?

Comment: @Tope yes, it's just adding the require that causes the problem.

Comment: It's difficult to expect an answer to this when you haven't explained how you set up your project's environment to support `import`. Are you using babel, webpack, browserify, or node.js harmony features? Oh nevermind, I just saw you're using rollup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

import is ES6 syntax. You either must use an experimental flag with nodejs or use babel to compile your js to be ES6 compatible.

EDIT:
Since the problem is with require and not import, i'm updating my answer.

I'm not sure what you're setup is but it's because, i'm guessing, google-cloud isn't written in es6. So you'll have to see if there's an es6 version in the src. If there is you could try (I doubt this will work)

Try:

```
import * as gcloud from 'google-cloud'
```

if that doesn't work - try a shimming module like riveted. You'll need webpack to compile this. Since you're using rollup.js, which i'm unfamiliar with you'll need a es5 to es6 compiler for this.

Comment: OK - the existing `imports` are working fine, it's the `require` that's causing the issue. What exactly do I need to do to the `gcloud` library to make it ES6-compatible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're setup is but it's because, i'm guessing, google-cloud isn't written in es6. So there's no export.modules in that module. Try: import * as gcloud from 'google-cloud' . if that doesn't work - try a shimming module like riveted. You'll need webpack to compile this.

Comment: @Garuuk he's using rollup, not webpack.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I'm unfamiliar with rollup - i'm sure Richard will need an es5 to es6 equivalent loader for rollup.